What does before mean in this sentence?

You showered before brushing your teeth?

Does it mean the person showered prior to brushing their teeth and does it imply that they brushed their teeth after they showered?

Why does the sentence confuse you? You clearly understand its meaning.

You showered before brushing your teeth?
It seems to be a question, expressed as a statement, asking whether you showered before brushing your teeth. It's not the usual form of the question ("Did you shower before brushing your teeth?"), but a question in response to something said, or because of an expectation.
Before means preceding (anterior to) in time.
If you showered first, your answer could be "Yes". If not, the answer would be "No."
